# MySQL ORDER By one Specific value in column (having comma separated values)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, find-in-set

I want to sort the user record according to city (chosen from the drop-down list). like if I pass city_id 22 in my query then i want all the row first which are having city_ids 22 then the rest of the rows.

I know `WHERE find_in_set('22',city_ids)` will give me the correct result but it will not return the all rows so I want to achieve it using some `ORDER BY` .

I have tried `ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET('22',city_ids)` but its not working. How do I fix this, any best way?

User Table:

```
Id    Name     city_ids
1     AAAAA    10,22,30
2     BBBBB    11,28
3     CCCCC    15,22,44
4     DDDDD    19,99,
5     EEEEE    55,27,22
```

Want Sorted Output like below:

```
Id    Name     city_ids
1     AAAAA    10,22,30
3     CCCCC    15,22,44
5     EEEEE    55,27,22
2     BBBBB    11,28
4     DDDDD    19,99,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
FIND_IN_SET('22', city_ids) > 0
```

will return `1` for all rows where `'22'` exists in column `city_ids` and `0` for the others. 
So, after that you need add one more level for sorting by `id` ascending:

```
ORDER BY 
  FIND_IN_SET('22', city_ids) > 0 DESC, 
  id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f9EktwPp57Vcfa4Q1weVfo/0).
Results:

```
| Id  | Name  | city_ids |
| --- | ----- | -------- |
| 1   | AAAAA | 10,22,30 |
| 3   | CCCCC | 15,22,44 |
| 5   | EEEEE | 55,27,22 |
| 2   | BBBBB | 11,28    |
| 4   | DDDDD | 19,99    |
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
ORDER BY (FIND_IN_SET('22', city_ids) > 0) DESC
```

This puts matches first.

Then you should fix your data model.  It is broken, broken, broken.  Storing lists of ids in a string is wrong for many reasons:

- The data types are (presumably) wrong.  The ids are numbers and should not be stored as strings.
- Storing multiple values in a column is not the SQL way to store things.
- Ids should have properly declared foreign key relationships, which you cannot declare.
- SQL does not have very good functions for processing strings.
- The resulting queries cannot take advantage of indexes or partitioning, impeding performance.
- SQL has this really great data structure for storing lists of things.  It is called a **table**, not a string column.

Comment: So how to achieve it without Storing multiple values in a column, is there any best mysql solution for my problem.

Comment: @amitgupta . . . You would use a junction/association table with one row per user and `city_id`.